# Ancient Radeon HD 6850 and Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card

I would like to run a recent Linux distro on a machine with Radeon HD 6850 (about 10 years old, nothing to do with rx 6800). I tried Ubuntu 21.04. The installation completes and X starts. The screen (4k) flickers and about its rightmost quarter represents what the OS thinks is its left (so parts of windows that would normally be off the right screen edge appear all the way on the left)

AMD used to publish a Linux driver, but the last version seems to be for the no-longer supported Ubuntu 14. The version no specific to a particular distribution also won't install.

It works fine under Windows 10.

Can someone please recommend something I could try, or confirm the best strategy is to give up. I can probably live without acceleration.

Comment: AMD haven't made a driver for that GPU series since 2015 [any platform]. They abandoned an entire swathe of cards with the advent of Win10. This is your choice of drivers for any platform [except Mac, who still supported these cards up to Mojave, 2018/19] - https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000-series/amd-radeon-hd-6850 I also think that series was only good to 2k, 1440p or maybe 1600. DP would always be a better bet than DVI [& avoid HDMI] for that type of card too - you didn't say what your connection is.

Comment: Some woes & discoveries… DP 1.2 MST required - https://forum.hardwareheaven.com/threads/amd-hd-6xxx-series-and-4k-displays.226759/

Comment: See the Debian [AMD/ATI Drivers](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo), which claims support for the Radeon HD 6850, although it relies on some experimental features. If this works, I can put up an answer.

Comment: Read up on how to make your own `xorg.conf`, and how to debug it (look at `/var/log/Xorg.log`, via `ssh` from a second computer, if necessary). Start with the `vesa` driver, that will very likely work (without acceleration). Then go through the various Radeon drivers; if necessary, try different modeline (or experiment with `xrandr`). If nothing works, it's also possible to go back to an older X version that is known to be compatible with a particular driver, but this will be a lot of effort, and you need to know how to compile things yourself.